# Facebook Create React App Build - Add Image As Prop Type

Tags: javascript, facebook, reactjs

I have a component comment.js

```
export default function Comment (props) {
return (
    <div className="comment-wrapper">
        <img src={props.userImage} />
        <p className="comment">{props.commentTitle}</p>
    </div>
);
}
```

So I just simply want to have that component in the parent component as

```
<Comment userImage="IMAGE_LINK" commentTitle="BLAH BLAH" />
```

Again, I am using the Create-React-App build system from facebook. With that being said I know I can hard code an image using the following

```
<img src={require(`./images/MY-IMAGE.png`)} />
```

The code above works perfectly fine for the test image I am trying to load. However, when needed dynamically for the component the issue gets a bit more complex.

Now with the comment.js component above, I cannot do

```
<img src={require("./images" + {props.userImage})} />
```

I have taken a look at one thread on this site as well as reading [this](https://simonsmith.io/using-webpack-to-build-react-components-and-their-assets/) blog post on the issue and can still not come to a conclusion.

How can I handle image assets being passed as props to a component, in this case?

Comment: What `require` is transformed into? It's not a standard built-in JS function.

Comment: You're right. The issue when using this build system is that you need to require a static asset for it to load. It is used as  a way of importing the asset for this build system. Without require, the image will not load. Got the information from [this](https://medium.com/@kathleeng.lopez/rendering-local-images-with-react-and-webpack-5f9d1fdb9b54) post.

Comment: @zerkms webpack will build a dependency graph based on what requires what then injects the code the most common scope.

Comment: @azium there is not even a single trace of a webpack in the question.

Comment: It's in the title actually. https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app

Comment: @azium Oh gosh, I thought it's just a statement "Create a react app" :-S

Comment: Let me clairfy that.

Comment: @zerkms hopefully new title was more specific and less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `import`

```
// parent component
import MenuImage from '/img/menu.png'

<Comment image={MenuImage} commentTitle="Title"} />
```

then on Comment component

```
export default props => (
  <img src={props.image} alt='' />
)
```